# How to send updated object list to Spring MVC controller

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jquery-ui-sortable

Suppose I have class User, I made a class with a list of Users and add this class object to a Model:

```
public class User {
   private String firstName;
   private String lastName;
   private Integer orderNumber;

   ...//getters and setters
}

public class Users {
   private List<User> users;

   ...//getter and setter
}
```

My Vies page :

```
<form role="form" method="POST" action="save" modelAttribute="users">
   <table>
      <thead>
         <tr>
            <th/>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
         </tr>
      </thead>
   <tbody>
    <c:forEach var="user" items="${users}">
       <tr>
          <td>${user.orderNumber}</td>
          <td>${user.firstName}</td>
          <td>${user.lastName}</td>
       </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</tbody>
</table>
    <button id="saveButton" type="submit">Save</button>
</form:form>
...
<script>
$("tbody").sortable({
   stop: function(event, ui) {
      $(this).find('tr').each(function(i) {
         $(this).find('td:first').text(i+1);
      });
   }
}).disableSelection();
</script>
```

When I click on the save button I want to bind users list with updated order number to post method on the controller:

```
@RequestMapping (method = POST, path = "/save")
public ModelAndView saveUsers(@ModelAttribute("users") Users users) throws Exception {
....
return new ModelAndView(..);
}
```

but users is always null.

how I can update current users list and get it in my controller?

Answer (score 0):

i cannot find 'td tag' in your html code.
if the tag exists, you cannot pass to `saveUsers` controller because you have no input tag. form tag can pass every data you want using input tag.

```
<form:form role="form" method="POST" action="save" modelAttribute="users">
   <table>
      <thead>
         <tr>
            <th/>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
         </tr>
      </thead>
   <tbody>
    <c:forEach var="user" items="${users}">

      <form:hidden path="orderNum" value="${user.orderNum}"/>
      <form:hidden path="firstName" value="${user.firstName}"/>
      <form:hidden path="lastName" value="${user.lastName}"/>
       <tr>${user.orderNum}</tr>
       <tr>${user.firstName}</tr>
       <tr>${user.lastName}</tr>
    </c:forEach>
</tbody>
</table>
    <button id="saveButton" type="submit">Save</button>
</form:form>
```

i guess it will work. a reason that input tag is hidden is for just passing not showing but data.